# Trying to add ScreenShots to my FB App detailed page, I can't see the option to add any?

Tags: screenshot, helper, facebook-page

I'm trying to add ScreenShots to my FB App detailed page however I have read the guidelines but on the actual detailed page can't see the option to add any? This is stopping me from submitting my completed APP Detailed Page.

I want to know how exactly screenshots are to be added (where the option button is), as I can't see any options!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "Website with Facebook Login" site url in "Setting > Basic" section, after that you can see "Screenshots" uploading area at the bottom of "App Details" section.